# Injecting Service into Multiple Domain Classes for Use in Views

Tags: grails

My goal is to be able to reuse some code among my various domain classes to ultimately end up populating various list boxes in my gsps.  I have a service but have had little luck plugging it in. Here's my code.

PopulateListBox Service:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH 
import groovy.sql.Sql

class PopulateListBox {

def dataSource = AH.application.mainContext.dataSource
def sql

def getStates(){

    sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    def states = []
    sql.eachRow("SELECT stvstat_desc FROM stvstat ORDER BY stvstat_desc"){
        states.add(it.stvstat_desc)
    }

    sql.close()

    [states:states]
}


}
```

Inside one of my domain classes I tried using it in my constraint block like so:

```
def PopulateListBox

static constraints = {
    nursingLicenseState(blank:false, inList:PopulateListBox.getStates())
}
```

But this doesn't appear to work.  How do I reference my service and still be able to access it from the domain class in my view?

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. You should really try and stick to the convention and have your services end in *Service
2. Where you inject the service into the domain object, the first letter needs to be lower-case.
3. When using a service in a domain object, you should declare it as `transient`.

So your service should be created (and Grails usually appends this by default):

```
class PopulateListBoxService {
    ...
}
```

And then your domain object should look something like:

```
class MyDomainObject {
    def populateListBoxService
    ...
    static transients=['populateListBoxService']
    ...
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Recreating with the name PopulateListBoxService I get a no signature of method error nursing.PopulateListBoxService.getStates().  Then it tells me a possible solution is getStates(). lol...

Comment: Are you creating the service with the `create-service` command?

Comment: I don't necessarily want to have this class be a service.  I just want it to be reusable so I don't have the bulk of the code in every controller that needs to use it.

Comment: I recreated it using the create-service command after you suggested I append Service to the end of it.  Originally I just created inside my IDE NetBeans.

Comment: I solved my problem by referencing the method of my service in the controller itself.  I had hoped to tie it into the domain class itself but this will work.  I also changed the return from a map to just returning the states array itself.

Comment: Unfortunately in Grails, because it uses Spring, normal classes are not Spring Beans, therefore you cannot inject them into other classes. You need to get familiar with dependency injection using Spring to understand why you could not do what you wanted to.